# How to check the clock frequency of a USB wifi dongle in linux/windows?

Tags: wifi

Is there any command that can show the clock frequency of a connected USB WiFi dongle in Linux/windows? I tried `lshw` in ubuntu for a USB dongle (Ralink Technology, Corp. MT7601U Wireless Adapter), but no clock information can be got.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's asking about software for windows, not unix.

Comment: Thanks, I modified the description, actually I can't get the clock information in Linux either.